# Interface builder constraints for Apple Watch: different layout even if settings is Any screen size

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit, xcode6.3

I have set my constraints in Xcode interface builder as following:

[image]

But the layout is not the same as the one I have on my interface builder (see below). I cannot see/find any property on the watch UI elements and views that allows me to set the **layout constraints**.

[image]

As you can see the grey button on the row is misaligned on the 42 mm watch. It works well on the 38mm watch.

**Anyone knows how to fix this?**

Answer (score 3):

There are no *constraints* on the Apple Watch. The interface can be layed out by groups with different behaviours.

So put your button in a group with horizontal layout and the desired width. Then put the button in that group and set the button's horizontal position to `right`.

Comment: It is a table with custom rows. So cannot really be tweaked with a group.

Comment: Where is the problem to put two groups on a custom table row?

Comment: It changes the appearances slightly as the group border takes off some space. Why are groups different that labels and buttons? I should still be able to put a button on the rightmost part of the row or is this not possible in WatchKit?

Comment: Did you try to set the Insets to `Custom` and play around with the inset values?